# I'm having flickering problems with meshes in blender2.83 especially in edit mode

Tags: mesh, artifacts

[image: A cube in exit mode with all the vertices selected. The flickering becomes more vigorous everytime I orbit]

After I opened blender 2.83, I deleted all objects in the default scene and added a cube. When I tabbed into edit mode, the faces are flickering. I tried to change the clipping distance to no avail. Since the cube is the only object in the scene, the problem can't be with overlapping geometry. What must I do? Notice the top face of the cube.

Comment: Maybe you don't have duplicate geometry, but you have duplicate faces. Try selecting a vertex and moving it around. This could be caused by you trying to extrude the cube, but then clicking away. To be honest, it is pretty hard to know.

Comment: This only happens when I toggle to edit mode in solid view. When I am in rendered view, no flickering occurs when I turn to edit mode.

Comment: @Eric Xue I already selected  all vertices and merged them by distance. That pretty much dissolves any double geometry. Besides, that cube is the only object in the scene and I hadn't performed anything on it yet aside from toggling to edit mode.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is caused by an anti-aliasing bug. You can disable anti-aliasing in "Preferences > Viewport > Quality", or wait for the next release.